# Visual Studio Code - Localizar los Class dentro de un proyecto

Tags: sublimetext3, vscode, teclado

Creo recordar que, como en el editor Sublime Text (que tampoco recuerdo), existe una combinación de teclas o extensión que ayuda a buscar todo CLASS definido en un proyecto ... algo del estilo <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>OTRA_TECLA</kbd>, aparece un panel en la parte superior de la pantalla y, ahí, tecleando el nombre del CLASS que se quiere buscar, aparecen las coincidencias de los posibles archivos que contienen ese CLASS o, directamente, su archivo de definición.

¿Alguien sabe la combinación de teclas a la que me refiero en Visual Studio Code? ¿y en Sublime Text aunque sea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depende del lenguaje que estés editando pero algunos comandos útiles son:

Si tienes abierto un espacio de trabajo (un carpeta con ficheros), pulsando <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> y a continuación empezando a teclear el nombre de un fichero podrás seleccionarlo y abrirlo. Como habitualmente (depende del lenguaje y de las prácticas de programación que utilices, cada fichero contendrá solo una clase y se llamará como la clase, es una forma de acceder a ellas.

Para abrir un espacio de trabajo (dependerá de como hayas hecho la instalación, pero en general):

- En **windows** ve a la carpeta con tu proyecto y haciendo boton derecho haz click en abrir con Code (*Open with Code*, si lo tienes en inglés).
- En **linux** desde la consola ve a la carpeta con tu proyecto y teclea `.code`
- En **mac** si alguien me dice como hacerlo en los comentarios, edito la respuesta (o que la edite directamente).

La documentación para navegar código en **Visual Studio Code** la encuentras [aquí](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved), y como podrás comprobar, depende de que el lenguaje que utilices la soporte no.

Comment: La combinación que terminé encontrando tras efectuar la pregunta fue la de La opción de [CTRL] y pulsar sobre el nombre de una clase que se resalta tras pasar el cursor sobre ella. Con la de [CTRL]+[P], aparece la lista para buscar entre archivos pero, a mí me parece que, solamente, afecta a los archivos que tienes abiertos o los que has abierto recientemente. No parece que tenga efecto sobre cualquier otro archivo que exista en el proyecto pero que no hayas abierto aún. Por eso, parece que se queda corta esa opción. A no ser que la emplee mal.

Comment: Para usar Ctrl+p tienes que abrir toda la carpeta en la que tienes el codigo como un espacio de trabajo. Te amplio la respuesta.

Comment: Es como suelo abrir los proyectos pero, al menos a mí, no me encuentra todos los archivos. Por ejemplo, últimamente trabajo con el framework de Laravel que dispone de una carpeta [vendor] dónde se ubican todas las dependencias PHP instaladas a través de Composer, igualmente, las propias dependencias del propio framework, es decir, todas sus clases de las que heredan las funcionalidades todos los componentes que se emplean en el proyecto. Si busco algunos de esos archivos por CTRL+P no me los encuentra si no los he abierto antes. Hice antes la prueba antes de escribir el comentario anterior.

Comment: a mi me ha funcionado, pero con un proyecto c#, con php no trabajo y no lo he probado. En cambio el buscar definiciones de clase al pasar sobre su nombre, no me ha funcionado... supongo que varia el soporte de la funcionalidad por lenguajes, o por como lo tengamos configurado.